# Error uplifting OGNL from 3.3.4 to 3.4.2 with struts2(6.3.0.2)

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

My application is based on struts2 (v 6.3.0.2) and I am currently using ognl v3.3.4 as one of its dependency. The application is working fine with these version.

When I try to uplift the OGNL to latest version i.e 3.4.2 I am getting the below error:

```
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setRoot(OgnlValueStack.java:102)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.<init>(OgnlValueStack.java:81)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.createValueStack(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:62)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.setContext(DefaultConfiguration.java:244)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:208)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.reload(ConfigurationManager.java:227)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.initialiseConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:84)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.wasConfigInitialised(ConfigurationManager.java:72)
                at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:61)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:1079)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:537)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:571)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:48)
                at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:60)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:244)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4311)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1014)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1866)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:816)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1584)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:312)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:925)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:735)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

from what I have found out is that `ognl.OgnlValueStack.setRoot` calls `ognl.Ognl.createDefaultContext`.
In 3.3.4 `createDefaultContext` return type was `Map`.
In 3.4.2 `createDefaultContext` return type is `OgnlContext`.
This incompatibility is the cause of error, but is there any solution to that from my code perspective? or its simply OGNL (3.4.2) is not compatible with struts2 (6.3.0.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`OgnlContext`](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/ognl/OgnlContext.html) ia a `Map<String, Object>`. In Struts 2 `OgnlContext` is set to [`ActionContext`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html) and [`ValueStack`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack.html) is a root object in it. For more information read:

- [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl)

> The framework sets the OGNL context to be our `ActionContext`, and the `ValueStack` to be the OGNL root object. (The `ValueStack` is a set of several objects, but to OGNL it appears to be a single object). Along with the value stack, the framework places other objects in the `ActionContext`, including maps representing the application, session, and request contexts. These objects coexist in the `ActionContext`, alongside the value stack (our OGNL root).

The `ActionContext` is *not* a `Map<String, Object>`, but you can get a context map with

```
OgnlContext context = (OgnlContext) ActionContext.getContext().getContextMap();
```

The `ValuStack` has there own context. There's also a `Map<String, Object>` you can get

```
OgnlContext context = (OgnlContext) ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().getContext();
```

Which version you use depends on implementation. You cannot just uplift a version of the API and use it with artifacts that require a lower version.